# Mysql SELECT by date format as 24 hour

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I am trying to select data from a table `mysql` but I need to format a `varchar` date column in a military format, but cannot get my desire output my query is below.

```
"SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`hour`, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') AS `time` FROM `dataTable`"
```

When I tried to echo the time below format appear.

```
2017-09-21 00:00:00
```

My desire output is below which is in 24 hour format and removing the seconds, any suggestions would be great.

```
2017-09-21 18:00
```

Comment: what date is stored in your database?

Comment: What is a *military format*?

Comment: STR_TO_DATE _creates_ a date from a specific format; if you want to format a existing date value before outputting it, you need to counterpart, DATE_FORMAT. And `%k` is hours without a leading zero, so you likely rather want `%H`

Comment: It is no good idea, to store dates as varchar

Comment: What is the data type of `hour`?

Comment: data type is in varchar it contains `2017-01-03 06:32:14am`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function of mysql.

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`hour`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS `time` FROM `dataTable`"
```

**Explanation:**

---

The `STR_TO_DATE` function always return the date in the format of **2008-09-15 22:23:00**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Monday 15th September 2008 22:23:00', '%W %D %M %Y %H:%i:%s');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Monday 15th September 2008 22:23:00', '%W %D %M %Y %H:%i:%s') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2008-09-15 22:23:00                                                        | 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Check the above example: the second parameter in `STR_TO_DATE` function is the format of the parameter 1 to tell the function that in which format parameter 1 is passed in the function.

[Reference taken from this link.](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)

Comment: @KaoriYui My pleasure to help you. :)